# How can I make sure a save file has finished writing before the program exits?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I'm writing a game using Libgdx and I discovered that on Android, when the home button is pressed and I go back into it, my game will increase the amount of memory allocated to it by about 1.5 - 2 MB each time.  I've tried to track down why that occurs but I have not been able to find it.  Anyway, I decided to close down my program instead of letting it remain in memory on android by using

```
System.exit(0);
```

By doing this, the memory gets cleared and I do not have to worry about that increase.  I know it is not ideal but I really can not track down the issue.

Problem is that now my save file does not finish writing everything before the program exits.

In my Save class:

```
public class Save
{
    //GameData class holds all of my values that need to be saved.
    public static GameData data =  new GameData();

    public static void saveData() thorws IOException
    {
        FileHandle file = Gdx.files.local("saveData.sav");

        OutputStream out = null;
        try
        {
            file.writeBytes(serialize(data), false;)
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            System.out.println(ex.toString());
        }
        finally
        {
            if (out != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    out.close();
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static byte[] serialize(Object obj) throws IOException
    {
        ByteArrayOutputStream b = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ObjectOutputStream o = new ObjectOutputStream(b);
        o.writeObject(obj);
        return b.toByteArray();
    }
}
```

In my Main class:

```
public class MainGame extends ApplicationAdapter
{
    public void create()
    {
        resume();
    }

    public void render()
    {
        //.....
    }

    public void resize()
    {
        //......
    }

    public void pause()
    {
         //set things that need to be saved

        //save
        try
        {
             Save.saveData();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //now I set my arraylists and pretty much everything else to null           
        //that can be set to null.  I was hoping this would fix the memory
        //increasing issue.  It helped but didn't fix it completely.

        //call dispose
        dispose();
    }

    public void resume()
    {
        //loads various things and determines if the game is to load from
        //save due to home being pressed or just load normally.
    }

    public void dispose()
    {
        //dispose of a few things

        //exit
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

How can I make sure that the program will only exit after all data has finished being output?
I've tried a few things on my own which didn't work so I'm hoping someone might be able to help.

Comment: You could save time and space by getting rid of the pointless `ByteArrayOutputStream` and just serializing directly to the file. You will probably need some form of synchronization or semaphoring to ensure you don't exit while the write is in progress.

Comment: it s better to find out what makes ur game use more memory.

Comment: @EliasFazel It is better than what?

Comment: I think Elias Fazel means it is better to find and fix the memory issue and not force the program to close using System.exit(0); while leaving the issue in the program.  I too think it is the best solution but I've spent a lot of time trying to fix it and it's still happening.

Comment: Looking at your code, you are assuming that the lifecycle of your static variables (the JVM) is the same as the lifecycle of your application, which it is not. So you'd better remove the static keyword or properly manage them instead of making such assumptions.